# Go to page based on selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an archive for my website but I'm stuck. I want users to select the year,month and week to be directed to the pages in that folder. I cant work out the javascript needed to capture the values and create a condition that directs the user. As well as adding a submit button. Thank you.

```html
<select id="year" name="year">
  <option value="#">year?</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="#">month?</option>
  <option value="jan">jan</option>
  <option value="feb">feb</option>
  <option value="mar">mar</option>
</select>

<select id="week" name="week">
  <option value="#">week?</option>
  <option value="wk1">1</option>
  <option value="wk2">2</option>
  <option value="wk3">3</option>
  <option value="wk4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="" value="Submit">
```

```js
var year = $('#year').val();
var month = $('#month').val();
var week = $('#week').val();

//some more code...where I get stuck

if (year==2015 && month==jan && week==2) {
  window.location = "2015/jan/wk1/monday.html";
} else if (year==2015 && month==jan && week==2) {
  window.location = "2015 / jan / wk2 / monday.html";
}
```

Comment: I don't get this `if (2015 && jan && wk1)` - If you're trying to get values that are equal to something, the syntax is `if (date==something && month==something && week==something)`

Comment: and this doesn't make sense `window.location = "2015 / jan / wk2 / monday.html";` what are you trying to do here? and you tagged as php but no code for it. Edit: I removed the tag for it.

Comment: I think you don't even need these conditions. Can't you just do something like `window.location = year + '/' + month + '/' + week + '/monday.html'` ?

Comment: you can directly say `window.location= year+"//"+month+"//"+week+"// monday.html"

Comment: 2015/jan/monday.html is the folder dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your code instead of success alert message. this will solve your prob hope so.

```js
var year = $('#year').val();
var month = $('#month').val();
var week = $('#week').val();
//some more code...where I get stuck
function urFunctin(){
if(document.getElementById("week").selectedIndex!=0)
  {
    if(document.getElementById("year").selectedIndex==0)
      {
        alert("Select year");
        document.getElementById("week").selectedIndex=0;
      }
    else if(document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex==0)
      {
        alert("Select month");
        document.getElementById("week").selectedIndex=0;
      }
    else{
    
      var year = $('#year').val();
      var month = $('#month').val();
      var week = $('#week').val();

      if(year && month && week)
      alert(year + "/" + month + "/" + week + "/monday.html");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="year" name="year">
  <option value="#">year?</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="#">month?</option>
  <option value="jan">jan</option>
  <option value="feb">feb</option>
  <option value="mar">mar</option>
</select>

<select id="week" name="week">
  <option value="#">week?</option>
  <option value="wk1">1</option>
  <option value="wk2">2</option>
  <option value="wk3">3</option>
  <option value="wk4">4</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="urFunctin();" value="SUBMIT">
```

Comment: Check the solution, let me know this is what you expecting??

Comment: it's okay, how do i trigger this with a submit button please

Comment: call the fuction on click event. add this code in your submit button.  onclick="urFunctin();"

Comment: and remove it from <select id="week" name="week" onchange="urFunctin();">

Comment: I have edited the answer now it should work as you want

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to redirect user to specific page if all selects have some value.
So set a common class to all these elements and set as default value empty string:

```
<select id="year" name="year" class="toRedirect">
  <option value="">year?</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select id="month" name="month" class="toRedirect">
  <option value="">month?</option>
  <option value="jan">jan</option>
  <option value="feb">feb</option>
  <option value="mar">mar</option>
</select>

<select id="week" name="week" class="toRedirect">
  <option value="">week?</option>
  <option value="wk1">1</option>
  <option value="wk2">2</option>
  <option value="wk3">3</option>
  <option value="wk4">4</option>
</select>
```

And then handle change event:

```
$(function() { // document ready wrapper, could be stripped out
  $('.toRedirect').on('change', function() {
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var month = $('#month').val();
    var week = $('#week').val();

    if(year && month && week)
       window.location = year + "/" + month + "/" + week + "/monday.html";
       // what about day, only monday???
  });
});
```

Comment: the days ran through mon-sun, how do i add this to a submit function? `<a href="javascript:myFunction()"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have got some wrong ideas about the comparison and logical statements and when comparing string you need to add the string in quotes.

```
var year = $('#year').val();
var month = $('#month').val();
var week = $('#week').val();

//some more code...where I get stuck

if (year != '#' && month != '#' && week  != '#') {
     window.location = year + '/' + month + '/' + week + '/monday.html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to handle it with the least JavaScript.

```
if ($('#year').val() != '#' 
  && $('#month').val() != '#' 
  && $('#week').val() != '#') {
    window.location = $('#year').val() + '/' 
      + $('#month').val() + '/' 
      + $('#week').val() + '/monday.html';
}
```

Although, the variables make it much more readable.